# Infix search on large table when majority of rows can be filtered out

Tags: postgresql, optimization, performance, postgresql-performance

We have a Postgres table, which looks like this:

```
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
| CLIENT_ID | VALUE_1 | VALUE_2 | VALUE_3 |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
|     11234 | aabcdef |   mnfng |  lflgbm |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
|     11234 |   xdfef | nfnvnaz | fngnnva |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
|     84590 |  pflghh |   otngp | cignral |
+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
|    ...    |   ...   |   ...   |   ...   |
```

`CLIENT_ID` is an indexed column.

We need to run a query which will return all the rows that belong to a specific `CLIENT_ID` and will have a particular substring in some of the columns `VALUE_X`.

Naive query for client id `11234` and substring `ng` would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE client_id = '11234' AND (value_1 LIKE '%ng%' OR
value_2 LIKE '%ng%' OR value_3 LIKE '%ng%')
```

The problem is that our table is large. It can possibly contain 10+ millions of rows. Rows can be first filtered by `CLIENT_ID` - then the subset of rows matching will only have about 100k+ rows.

Our tests show that when the table is relatively small, the database does a sequential scan of the whole table. It's not very fast, but it's reasonably fast (about 1s). When the table gets larger, the database first filters the rows with a specific `CLIENT_ID` (which is indexed) and then does sequential scan of the rest. This is super slow (about 30s+).

Is there any way how we can speed this up, only by using Postgres (we don't want to introduce Elasticsearch etc.)?

We are currently using Postgres 10.9 in production, but we can possibly upgrade to the latest version, if there is significant performance gain (our staging tests show there are not).

Thank you.

*Note that there are already threads on speeding up infix searches, but this case is more specific - we can possibly filter many of the rows out otherwise.*

Comment: "first filters the rows with a specific CLIENT_ID (which is indexed) and then does sequential scan of the rest."  I don't know what this means.  Please show the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)

Comment: The `OR` condition on three different columns doesn't really make that easier. You could try one [trigram index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) for each column and hope for a bitmap or for the conditions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name '%ng%' contains no trigrams, so if that is an accurate example he won't get any help there.  Index only scan is probably the best bet.

Comment: @jjanes: do you mean `ng` is too short for the trigram index?

Comment: Right.  For a LIKE query, it can't bad out short words with spaces, unless the space (or punctuation, or actual beginning or ending of the string) was there in the original.

Comment: @jjanes: some simple tests show me that a trigram index **is** used even for short strings like that

Comment: Probably does not help at all, but you can try: `select T.* from T cross join lateral ( values (T.value_1), (T.value_2), (T.value_3)) as X(value) where T.clientid = 11234 and X.value like '%mn%'`   or `select T.* from T where clientid = 11234 and '#' || T.value_1 || '#' || T.value_2 || '#' || T.value_3 || '#' like '%#%mn%#%'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It can be **used**, it is just pretty horrible.  It will have to stuff the bitmap with every tuple pointer in the index (which is the same as every tuple pointer in the table (unless it is a partial index--and I'm not sure how effective even that is).  So it effectively does a seq scan on the table, just with the overhead of an index scan superimposed.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your input. My colleague just solved the problem by using Trigram index on the `VALUE_N` columns. Now the queries run under 10ms.

Answer (score 0):

Taking 30+ seconds suggests that not enough of the data is in cache.  Maybe you could just throw more RAM at it.

If you are actually searching for just two characters with a % tight on each side, then a pg_trgm index will not help you.  Although perhaps you could compile your own version as a bigram index.

If your table has only those 4 columns (or it has more, but you only select some subset of these 4 rather than using *), then you could use this index:

```
create index on tbl (client_id, value_1, value_2, value_3);
```

and get an index-only scan.

If that doesn't work for you because you need more columns, then you could add to this index the primary/unique key (here called `id`), and then query like so:

```
create index on tbl (client_id , id, value_1, value_2, value_3);

SELECT tbl.* from 
    (select id FROM tbl WHERE client_id = '99' AND (value_1 LIKE '%ng%' ORvalue_2 LIKE '%ng%' OR value_3 LIKE '%ng%')) t 
    join tbl using (id);
```

It is a bit of a shame that PostgreSQL isn't clever enough to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought indices don't work for infix search, just for a prefix one. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @petr, they don't but the idea behind a covering index is that when   client_id is found, value_x is included in the index leaf, so there is no need to fetch that from the table to check if it satisfies the predicate.

Comment: The slow part is not evaluating the LIKE operator, it is stomping all over the table, probably either in random order or sparsely, to get the data to use in the evaluation.  The index concentrates the relevant data where it can be fetched efficiently for an index-only-scan.